# Перевод в integer число, для которого в list указанны индексы единичных бит

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Как можно без цикла и быстро перевести в integer число, для которого в list указанны индексы единичных бит. Интересная и обратная операция.

Например:

```
List = [20, 80, 1] указаны позиции единичных бит. 
Ожидаемый результат 2^20+2^80+2^1=1208925819614629175754754
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

быстрые (векторизированные) функции, которые написаны на C / Cython работают со строго-типизированными данными, где максимальной точностью для целых чисел является `np.uint64`, которые в свою очередь должны лежать в диапазоне `[0, 2^64-1]`.

```
In [31]: np.iinfo(np.uint64)
Out[31]: iinfo(min=0, max=18446744073709551615, dtype=uint64)

In [32]: 2**64 - 1
Out[32]: 18446744073709551615
```

Соответственно если вы хотите возвести `2` в степень большую `63` вам придется использовать медленную реализацию `Vanilla Python`.

Для чисел которые попадают в диапазон `int64` или `unint64` можно использовать методы Numpy:

```
In [33]: lst = [20, 60, 1]

In [34]: np.power(2, lst, dtype="int64").sum()
Out[34]: 1152921504607895554
```

---

Медленная реализация:

```
res = sum(2**i for i in lst)
```

Comment: а в битовый массив можно перевести  по аналогии одной строчкой?

Comment: плиз медленную реализацию тоже покажи. Мне нужно работать с 80 битами. В инете не нашел зацепку.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, думаю можно, немного пошаманив с [np.binary_repr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html)